# I am facing issues for Get Container ACL and Set Container ACL REST API using postman using AAD Token as authentication

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am getting following error while making REST API call to [Get Container ACL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-container-acl) using Postman :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
    <Message>The specified resource does not exist.
RequestId:35678849-101e-005b-0fa8-d4c9bd000000
Time:2021-11-08T13:53:42.8102881Z</Message>
</Error>
```

and following error while making REST call to [Set Container ACL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-container-acl) using Postman :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>ResourceNotFound</Code>
    <Message>The specified resource does not exist.
RequestId:35688854-101e-005b-12a8-d4c9bd000000
Time:2021-11-08T13:58:12.8507122Z</Message>
</Error>
```

Not sure what I am missing is it right permissions or right params ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested the same using the `AAD Authorization` method and faced the same issue for only ACL Operations while other operations (like list blob) were successful.

[image]

[image]

As **@SumanthMarigowda-MSFT** mentioned `AAD auth` is not supported in the ACL operations . You have to use `Shared Key Auth`.

**Steps:**

1. Create environment variables as below:

   [image]

   **Note:** Only initial value for the highlighted variables are to be provided , others should be left blank.
2. Create a request
   `https://{{azure_storage_account}}.blob.core.windows.net/yourcontainername?restype=container&comp=acl`
   with `Get/Put` as per your requirement and adding the below
   `headers` :

   [image]
3. Add the below code in the `Pre-Request Script` Tab in Postman:

   ```
   const crypto = require("crypto-js");

   // Set Date header value for authorization
   // Should be UTC GMT string
   pm.environment.set("header_date", new Date().toUTCString());
   console.log("header date", new Date().toUTCString());
   var substituteEnvVars = function (varStr) {
       let match;
       let replacedVar = varStr;

       while ((match = /\{\{([^{}]*?)}}/g.exec(replacedVar)) !== null ) {
           if (!pm.variables.get(match[1])) {
               continue;
           }
           var envVar = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(match[0]), 'g');
           replacedVar = replacedVar.replace(envVar, pm.variables.get(match[1]));
       }

       return replacedVar;
   };

   // Get hash of all header-name:value
   const headers = pm.request.getHeaders({ ignoreCase: true, enabled: true });

   // Construct Signature value for Authorization header
   var signatureParts = [
       pm.request.method.toUpperCase(),
       headers["content-encoding"] || "",
       headers["content-language"] || "",
       pm.request.body.toString().length || "",
       headers["content-md5"] || "",
       headers["content-type"] || "",
       headers["x-ms-date"] ? "" : (pm.variables.get("header_date") || ""),
       headers["if-modified-since"] || "",
       headers["if-match"] || "",
       headers["if-none-match"] || "",
       headers["if-unmodified-since"] || "",
       headers["range"] || ""
   ];

   // Construct CanonicalizedHeaders
   const canonicalHeaderNames = [];
   Object.keys(headers).forEach(key => {
       if (key.startsWith("x-ms-")) {
           canonicalHeaderNames.push(key);
           console.log("key: ", canonicalHeaderNames);
       }
   });
   // Sort headers lexographically by name
   canonicalHeaderNames.sort();

   const canonicalHeaderParts = [];
   canonicalHeaderNames.forEach(key => {
       let value = pm.request.getHeaders({ ignoreCase: true, enabled: true })[key];
       console.log("value: ",value);
       // Populate variables
       value = substituteEnvVars(value);
       console.log("value: ",value);
       // Replace whitespace in value but not if its within quotes
       if (!value.startsWith("\"")) {
           value = value.replace(/\s+/, " ");
           console.log("value: ",value);
       }

       canonicalHeaderParts.push(`${key}:${value}`);
       console.log("canonicalHeaderParts: ",canonicalHeaderParts);
   });

   // Add headers to signature
   signatureParts.push.apply(signatureParts, canonicalHeaderParts);

   // Construct CanonicalizedResource
   const canonicalResourceParts = [
       `/${pm.environment.get("azure_storage_account")}${pm.request.url.getPath()}`
   ];
   console.log("canonicalResourceParts: ",canonicalResourceParts);
   const canonicalQueryNames = [];
   pm.request.url.query.each(query => {
       canonicalQueryNames.push(query.key.toLowerCase());
       console.log("canonicalQueryNames: ",query.key.toLowerCase());
   });
   canonicalQueryNames.sort();
   canonicalQueryNames.forEach(queryName => {
       const value = pm.request.url.query.get(queryName);
       console.log("canonicalQueryNames: ",value);
       // NOTE: This does not properly explode multiple same query params' values
       // and turn them into comma-separated list
       canonicalResourceParts.push(`${queryName}:${value}`);
       console.log("canonicalResourcePartss: ",canonicalResourceParts);
   });
   // Add resource to signature
   signatureParts.push.apply(signatureParts, canonicalResourceParts);

   console.log("Signature Parts", signatureParts);

   // Now, construct signature raw string
   const signatureRaw = signatureParts.join("\n");

   console.log("Signature String", JSON.stringify(signatureRaw));

   // Hash it using HMAC-SHA256 and then encode using base64
   const storageKey = pm.environment.get("azure_storage_key");
   const signatureBytes = crypto.HmacSHA256(signatureRaw, crypto.enc.Base64.parse(storageKey));
   const signatureEncoded = signatureBytes.toString(crypto.enc.Base64);

   console.log("Storage Account", pm.environment.get("azure_storage_account"));
   console.log("Storage Key", storageKey);

   // Finally, make it available for headers
   pm.variables.set("header_authorization", 
       `SharedKey ${pm.environment.get("azure_storage_account")}:${signatureEncoded}`);
   ```
4. Then Save and Send the request you will get the output as below:

   [image]

**Reference for Pre-request Script:**

[Github](https://github.com/kamranayub/azure-storage-rest-postman/blob/master/Azure%20Storage%20REST%20API.postman_collection.json)

Answer (score 0):

[Get Container ACL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-container-acl) & [Set Container ACL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/set-container-acl) only supports SharedKey authentication for now. They don’t support AAD authentication.