# List folder in Azure Gen2 storage account with sas

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake-gen2, sas-token, shared-access-signatures

I generated a sas token with the list permission for a folder in a datalake storage account gen2. 
Howerver when I try to access it with an httpGet request, I get AuthorizationPermissionMismatch error This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission 
I know that to list a container with httpRequest we have to add &comp=list&restype=container in the queryString. Is there any specific param to add for listing a folder

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and include your request URL. Do obfuscate the account name and sig portion of the SAS before sharing.

Comment: The url that I use is the one generated by azure when creating the sas token

Comment: Can you please share that?

Comment: https://datalake01.blob.core.windows.net/container01/api-access?sp=l&st=2022-01-19T14:26:48Z&se=2022-01-21T22:26:48Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=d&sig=rlae7Vxq1D3rVIW%2FovAK4Trp7UJFqidAF0aW7rIHf88%3D&sdd=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I am facing issues for Get Container ACL and Set Container ACL REST API using postman using AAD Token as authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69884958/i-am-facing-issues-for-get-container-acl-and-set-container-acl-rest-api-using-po)

Comment: No I am not using AD authentication, I am trying to use sas to aceess a folder with an httpget request. It works on container level but not in folder level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Once you have generated the SAS token on the container level using the required permissions. You can add a directory filter in the rest API like below :***

```
https://<StorageURL>/<Container>?directory=<DirectoryName>&restype=container&comp=list&<SASToken>
```

***I tested the same in my environment . I created ADLS Gen 2 Storage account , a test container and then a directory named as Folder and added few files in it  as shown below :***

[image]

***Then using SAS generated on container level , I called the below Rest API :***

```
https://adlsgen2ansuman.blob.core.windows.net/test?directory=folder&restype=container&comp=list&sp=racwdlmeop&st=2022-02-03T06:55:43Z&se=2022-02-03T14:55:43Z&spr=https&sv=2020-08-04&sr=c&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

**Output:**

[image]